# How can i search in data base through mysql using php variables & loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want a bit help in searching from database. I had used nested loop for searching in different tables & columns.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mobirise");

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    if(!empty ($_POST['stext'])){
        $query = $_POST['stext'];
        $min_length = 3;
        if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){
            $sql_r= $mysqli->query("show tables from mobirise;");
            while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_r)) {
                $res=$table[0];
                //print"$res"."<br>";
                $sql_i= $mysqli->query("show columns from ".$res.";");
                while($tables = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_i)) {
                    $reslt=$tables[0];
                    //print"&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;"."$reslt"."<br>";
                    $raw_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $res WHERE $reslt LIKE '%".$query."%'");
                    print_r($raw_results);?><br><?php
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Printing Result like that

```
{
    mysqli_result Object ( 
        [current_field] => 0 
        [field_count] => 8 
        [lengths] => 
        [num_rows] => 0 
        [type] => 0 
) 
}
```

but i want table data.

Comment: Please explain a little bit more

Comment: You did a **fetch** after all the other queries, so why not do one after the last one as well, to get access to all the columns returned by `SELECT *` ???

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly for your reponse.
i want to print table data which is found likely search query.

Comment: I want to print data of table like this-> https://ibb.co/YPjSyyF
but am not getting proper format.

Comment: print_r is a debug tool, it does not magically create HTML tables for you, that is something you have to do on your own. What have you tried so far? You know how to loop over the records in a result set, and how to loop over the items in an array - yes? (If no, time to start reading up on these basics.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.
Am just forgetting mysqli_fetch_array statement.
Updated Code >

```
        <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mobirise");
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    if(!empty ($_POST['stext'])){
        $query = $_POST['stext'];
        $min_length = 3;
        if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){
            $sql_r= $mysqli->query("show tables from mobirise;");
            while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_r)) {
                $res=$table[0];
                $sql_i= $mysqli->query("show columns from ".$res.";");
                while($tables = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_i)) {
                    $reslt=$tables[0];
                    $raw_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $res WHERE $reslt LIKE '%".$query."%'");
                    print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

?>

Now am getting my Exact Output.